# import_array doesn't work in debug build in embedded Python C API

Tags: python, c++

I have the following problem: I am using the embedded Python C API from C++ to execute Python code. Everything works so far in Release Mode, but as soon as I start to run the Debug Mode, I get the error:

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

when calling from C++:

```
Py_Initialize();
import_array();
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full program code; if you check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html), it recommends putting the line:

`Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */`

Before you make the *Py_Initialize()* function call.

*"The Py_SetProgramName() function should be called before Py_Initialize() to inform the interpreter about paths to Python run-time libraries"*

Make sure your main function has the argv argument like the example in the docs.

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                 "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! The Py_Initialize part is not the problem. That runs perfectly. I copied your code but as soon as I write PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy") I get an error that it cannot import multiarray. In Release mode it runs perfectly, I have this problem just in Debug mode.

Comment: Hey!, when you say you are running in debug/release mode im assuming you mean visual studio? Because the documents say: _if you have a C++ project loaded then the native C++ debugger will be used by default_ (in short). See the link attached for the [mixed mode debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode)

Comment: Hi! Yes I mean Visual Studio. I don't need to debug inside the python code but I need to be able to debug my C++ code. So I don't have any Python project loaded in Visual Studio.